# Rindler coordinates and objects possibly exceeding the speed of light

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, acceleration, speed-of-light

Assume $c=1$

So I've been on a bit of a journey trying to derive special relativity by myself and in doing so was analyzing the viewpoint of a uniformly accelerating observer.

I was particularly interested in how a uniformly accelerated observer (hyperbolic worldline) would observe an inertial observer (linear worldline).

Doing some math I found the inertial worldlines to take on this bell-curve like shape:

Acceleration $=1$

(Top is inertial perspective, stationary worldline in red)

(Bottom is hyperbolic/accelerated perspective)

[image]
[image]

Now this itself is pretty weird, given that if we do it for multiple inertial worldlines we see that all of them have a horizontal asymptotes at $x=-1$, implying that an accelerating observer would see the objects passing it becoming thinner and stacking up like plates.

With this I was sure that I had screwed up my math somehow, but after some research I found the "Rindler Coordinates" and the "Rindler Horizon" which seemed to match my findings, my coordinates just being the Rindler shifted down by 1 unit.

But a problem still remained, if we start with a different inertial-worldline stationary in the initial frame, say at $x=2$, this is the Rindler-worldline:

[image]

And there it is, the slope of the worldline seems to exceed c.

Here shown explicitly through a derivative:

[image]

The object at a point travels at $1.5c$

Now here are my guesses as to what's happening:

a.) Just as the points passing the observer probably don't converge to one unit away in any meaningful sense, the objects exceeding the speed of light in the accelerating frame probably don't do it an any meaningful/paradoxical way.

b.) My math is just wrong, these are not the correct worldlines and the speed of light is not exceeded.

c.) My math is wrong, but the speed of light is still exceeded in a different way.

For reference this is the equation for the bell-curve like worldlines:

$\frac{b+\frac{1}{a}}{\cosh\left(at\right)-v\sinh\left(at\right)}-\frac{1}{a}$

Where $a$ is the acceleration of the hyperbola, $b$ is the shift up and down of the inertial worldline, and $v$ is the velocity of the inertial worldline.

Any answers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will use the more standard Rindler coordinates ($a=1$):
$$
\begin{align}
t &= X\sinh T & x &= X\cosh T
\end{align}
$$
with $t,x$ inertial coordinates and $T,X$ your accelerated frame and $a$ the proper acceleration. It's essentially the same as your coordinates, only $X$ is translated so that the observer performing hyperbolic motion is at position $X = 1$ (instead of $X=0$). It has the advantage of making analogies with polar coordinates more easily and setting the Rindler horizon at $X=0$ (instead of $X=-1$) which is where the coordinate system is singular.

Your mistake is to assume that the condition of not crossing the speed of light is:
$$
\left|\frac{dX}{dT}\right|<1
$$
This cannot be true as the speed of light limit would depend on the coordinate system. It's easier to arrive at a coordinate independent definition by thinking geometrically. Not crossing the speed of light means that the 4-velocity along the worldline is always time-like, i.e. inside the future region bounded by the future lightcone. Quantitatively, to check whether the 4-velocity is time-like, you therefore need to apply the metric $ds^2$ to it and check its sign.

In an inertial frame (using the $(+,-,-,-)$ convention):
$$
ds^2 = dt^2-dx^2
$$
Being time like means $ds^2>0$, so you do recover:
$$
\left|\frac{dx}{dt}\right|<1
$$

However, this only applies for inertial frames where the metric always has the same expression. In a general coordinate system, the expression of the expression of the metric is more complicated. Geometrically, the light cone is typically distorted and physically, you can interpret it as the speed of light acquiring a space-time dependence as well as a directional dependence in general.

This is what happens for Rindler coordinates. The metric in the new coordinate system is:
$$
ds^2 = dt^2-dx^2 = X^2dT^2-dX^2
$$
At the event $T,X$, the speed of light is:
$$
c=|X|
$$
It therefore acquires a spatial dependence. In your example, the speed of $1.5$ is reached at a position $X>1.5$ so the particle did not cross the speed of light. Remember that even if on your graph $X_0\sim 1.1$, my $X$ is shifted by $1$, so $X\sim 2.1>1.5$, so you are far from the speed of light. Note that in your case, at the position of the accelerated observer $X = 1$, there is not distortion as expected, since the local frame is just boosted with respect to an inertial frame.

In general, to conserve the value and isotropy of the speed of light, you'll need to use conformal maps, i.e. maps that preserve angles so that the light cone is preserved. For the accelerated frame, you can change the Rindler coordinates to Radar (or Lass) coordinates:
$$
\begin{align}
t &= e^{\tilde X}\sinh T & x &= e^{\tilde X}\cosh T \\
X &= e^{\tilde X} & \tilde X &= \ln X
\end{align}
$$
which are conformal:
$$
ds^2 = e^{2\tilde X}(dT^2-d\tilde X{}^2)
$$
This time, the speed of light is always $c=1$ as in the inertial case. You can map the inertial motion in this new coordinate system and check that the speed of light is still never crossed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I realize now that the light cone itself is distorted and that the inertial worldline never escapes it, but I do have a question.

Just to be clear, the observed speed of light changes over time?

If that is the case, although the speed of light changes, there are still points in time where the inertial worldline appears to progress faster than it, even though it never manages to escape the light cone.

Would it be more accurate then for me to say that the speed of a light ray is always faster than the inertial worldline at a crossing with it, so locally it's always faster?

Comment: In Rindler coordinates, the speed of light is still constant in time $T$, it depends only in space $X$ (though from the perspective of an observer, it will depend on its proper time, perhaps this is what you were alluding to?). I don't get what you mean by the apparent crossing, since the speed of light is defined by the light cone. Yes, for your final interpretation, this is how physically interpret the light cone, as the four velocities of light rays moving from an event.

Answer (score 1):

Below, I have plotted 3 of these bell curves (green) that represent the wordlines of free falling inertial observers with $B = 5, 15$ and $30$ from the point of view of a 'master' accelerated observer at $B=15$ at time $T=0$. (I have rotated the chart so that distance is horizontal and time is vertical as per convention.)

[image: Inertial worldlines in accelerated Rindler chart]

I have also plotted light curves (magenta dashed curves) that intersect the x axis where the inertial worldlines cross the x axis. These represent the light cones and the important thing to note is that the free falling observers always remain within their respective light cones and therefore never exceed the speed of light as measured in this coordinate system.

However, it can also be noted that the speed of light varies in this coordinate system. The light cone at $B=5$ is narrow and light rays appear to have a gradient of less than one and the light cone at $B=30$ is broad and appears to have a gradient of greater than one. Only the light cone at $B=15$ where the accelerating observer is located has a gradient of one locally at time $T=0$. This is actually correct, because by the equivalence principle, the point of view of the accelerated observers is equivalent to the point of view of an observer at rest in a gravitational field (locally). The accelerated observer at $B=15$ sees light lower down in the gravitational field as moving slow and light higher up in the gravitational field as moving fast. This is all perfectly acceptable and well known in general relativity. If you look at green worldline of the free falling inertial observer with $B= 30$, you can see that she appears to have a falling gradient of greater than one, but this is not a problem as long as she is not exceeding the local speed of light as measured in these coodinates.

If we look at the [Rindler coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates) in their metric form:

$$ d s^2 = -(a t)^2 + d x^2 + d y ^2 +d z^2$$

and set $ds =0$ because we are considering the worldline of a photon and solve for motion $\frac {dx}{dt}$ only in the x direction (so $\frac {dy}{dt}=0$ and $\frac {dz}{dt}=0$), we get the velocity of the light to be:

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = (at)^2$$

which confirms that in these coordinates, the vertical velocity of light depends on the proper acceleration of the observer and varies with time.

> Now this itself is pretty weird, given that if we do it for multiple
> inertial worldlines we see that all of them have a horizontal
> asymptotes at x=−1, implying that an accelerating observer would see
> the objects passing it becoming thinner and stacking up like plates.

The inertial objects do indeed get closer together and stack up as they asymptotically approach the Rindler event horizon, similarly to how a stationary accelerated observer in the Schwarzschild metric measures free falling objects to asymptotically approach the event horizon at the Schwarzschild radius $r = \frac{ 2GM}{c^2}$.

There are a few minor errors in your equation. It can be corrected by removing the $1/a$ factors and it will then match the regular Rindler curve and the offset behaves nicely:

$$\frac{b}{cosh(at) - v \ sinh(at)}$$

To keep things simple set $v=0$ so we just consider inertial observers that are stationary in Minkowski spacetime and solve for t to rotate the whole curve so that the equation is in the regular format, with distance horizontal and time vertical as in a standard Minkowski chart:

$$t = \frac1a arccosh\left(\frac Bx\right)$$